# How to use array in case statement in bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

While writing a bash script I encountered a problem where I want to use array in case statement to run commands.
For example if my array contains

```
1 2 3
```

and my case have conditions

```
1)
  echo "Hello"
  ;;

2)
  echo "call"
  ;;

3)
  echo "bye"
  ;;

*)
  echo "Unknown"
  ;;
```

then it print output

```
Hello
call
bye
```

for all the items stored in my array should check for the conditions.
while doing so I tried this

```
case ${!arr[@]} in
  1)
    echo "Hello"
    ;;

  2)
    echo "call"
    ;;

  3)
    echo "bye"
    ;;

  *)
    echo "Unknown"
    ;;
esac
```

but it didnt work out anyone can help me.

If some mistake. Please dont flag my post

Comment: Do you use `bash` or `zsh`?

Comment: basically i am working for both @Cyrus but i prefer `bash`

Comment: @PradyumnaKrishna : I remove the tags zsh and sh, because they are not related to your question.

Comment: @PradyumnaKrishna : If you do a `echo ${!arr[@]}`, you will see that this expands to `0 1 2` (the indices of `arr`), and  this does not make sense in a `case` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to loop over the array and thus apply the case statement to each element in turn:

```
for element in "${arr[@]}"; do
    case ${element} in
    1)
        echo "Hello"
        ;;

    2)
        echo "call"
        ;;

    3)
        echo "bye"
        ;;

    *)
        echo "Unknown"
        ;;
    esac
done
```